# Terraform script to create multiple api gateway with multiple resources and methods

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I am creating multiple api gateway using terraform,
each api gateway has multiple resources and methods:

```hcl
variable "api_gateway" {
  type = map(object({
    name        = string
    status_code = number
    resource = map(object({
      resource_name = string,
      method = map(object({
        method_names = string
      }))
    }))
  }))

  default = {
    apigateway1 = {
      name        = "firstapi"
      status_code = 200
      resource = {
        resource_name1 = {
          resource_name = "firstresource"
          method = {
            method1 = {
              method_names = "POST"
            },
            method2 = {
              method_names = "PUT"
            }
          }
        }
        resource_name2 = {
          resource_name = "secondresource"
          method = {
            method1 = {
              method_names = "POST"
            },
            method2 = {
              method_names = "PUT"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    apigateway2 = {
      name        = "secondapi"
      status_code = 200
      resource = {
        resource_name1 = {
          resource_name = "firstresource"
          method = {
            method1 = {
              method_names = "DELETE"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to create the multiple resource within each api, even if resource have one method, but when resource have multiple methods, as in the the `firstapi`, I am not able to achieve it, please help with that.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: `when resource have multiple method ... i am not able to achieve it` why not?  ... are you getting an error? ... all you have provided is the input we need more details

Comment: Hi @HelderSepulveda, i am using for loop with flatten method with above input,, it is producing a tuple with all flatten elements, by using that tuple i am able to create required api, and the resources, but when it come to method creation,  getting "Error: creating API Gateway Resource: ConflictException: Another resource with the same parent already has this name: firstresource" error.

Comment: @PoojaSahu don't you think that `for loop with flatten method` is important for others to attempt reproducing your issue?

Comment: then what is solution???

Comment: Hi @HelderSepulveda, could you please provide some solution, on it.

Comment: All you have provided here is a variable ... there is nothing anyone can do to help with only that